# Dual boot no longer working

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 with dual boot. Dual boot with Windows 10 seemed to work well. Then I immediately upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04, and I could successfully boot into Ubuntu. However from the first time I decided to reboot from Windows 10, the dual boot menu no longer shows up at startup.

I now started Ubuntu from the USB "Try Ubuntu". I installed boot-repair and you can find the diagnostic [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26339392/). I haven't actually tried to repair yet, I would like to have some expert advice before proceeding. Thanks!

Comment: do you hav "fast startup" turned off in Windows? This option is actually a hibernate and may interfere with grub.

Comment: @GaganRajput into Windows 10.

Comment: 17.04 expires this month, and if Lenovo do not use 17.10 until fixes are made, perhaps as soon as this next week. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147  While Ubuntu should install and work with UEFI Secure boot on, you then cannot install any proprietary drivers and many systems need proprietary drivers to work well. What model Lenovo? What video card/chip?

Comment: @ravery I turned it off but nothing changes.

Comment: if your system does not allow OS selection then this answer will, set grub for boot, https://askubuntu.com/a/923145/694267.

Comment: Have you tried boot-repair? I don't think it will harm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for you, but it worked for me when I had the same issue.

First, go to your BIOS settings, and go to System Configuration. From there, select Boot Options.

Under Boot Options, you should have a list called UEFI boot order or boot sequence or something similar. The first option in that list will probably be OS Boot Manager. Highlight that option using your arrow keys, and press Enter.

If I'm right, a dialog box like thing will pop up, and it'll display two options. Windows Boot Manager as the first option, and Ubuntu as the second. Press F5 to move Windows Boot Manager to the bottom, below Ubuntu, and then press F10, and then F10 again to save and exit.

After all these steps, your system will reboot, and hopefully, the GRUB menu should appear again. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, my BIOS settings don't have any option related to boot order (I have a Lenovo laptop)

Comment: @splinter123 -- none? not even device boot order???

Comment: @splinter123 I had this same issue on a friend's laptop, and it was a Lenovo laptop. Could you show us a picture of your BIOS screen?

Comment: @splinter123 And also, I don't know if all Lenovo laptops have this, but most of them have this button on the left hand side called the Novo Button, and it's used to access the BIOS. If that's how you access it, then before selecting BIOS setup (after pressing the Novo Button), there should be an option called Boot Options. And if you select that, you'll be given the option of choosing which OS to boot into.