# How to get grub on a dual boot with Win 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

After several modifications to settings in Win 10 Home (Boot sequence changed, Secure Boot had to be disabled and Device Encryption had to be turned off), Ubuntu 20.04 finally installed along side Windows. However, restarting after removing the installation device (a USB thumb drive) it booted directly into Windows. Any restart goes directly to Windows. What must be done to get a grub menu so a choice of OS's can be made? This is on an 2020 HP ENVY laptop.

Comment: do you get the option to boot into linux with F12? (press it repeatedly after pushing the power button)

Comment: Have you updated UEFI? And HP does not seem to work with efibootmgr which grub also uses to reset boot order. You should be able to change boot order in UEFI settings. Otherwise you have to use HP's boot keys. while many systems use f12, HP often uses HP - escape + F9 for boot menu, F10 for UEFI/BIOS setup

Comment: F9 only gives the options of OS Boot manager (UEFI) Windows or Boot From EFI File. F10 key only allows altering the order in which the boot devices are accessed, not which OS is wanted. How do you update UEFI to change OS boot order?

Answer (score 0):

1. In your windows, install [EasyBCD](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/3112-easybcd.html) and define your Ubuntu.
2. When you can get access in the Ubuntu, set the main boot loader there. Like using boot-repair. Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/923136/how-to-set-grub-as-the-boot-manager)

Comment: EasyBCD is really for old BIOS/MBR based systems: https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/uefi/